# WPA technical doubts (3)

Tags: diffie-hellman, algorithm, handshake, wpa3

This is the third post about the set of doubts that came up when I tried to understand WPA3. I am new to this world of cyber-security so every bit of help is welcome!

Someone told me that in WPA2 forward secrecy is achieved by generating ephemeral keys through the handshake’s nonces, but I couldn't find how WPA3 achieves it exactly (could not find info regarding nonces in WPA3). Could someone shed some light on this?

But then I read that WPA2 could not achieve perfect forward secrecy because of having a pre-shared key (PSK), since the  ephemeral keys are derived from the PSK so if an attacker knows the PSK then he could manage to decrypt old messages had they captured them. Is this correct?

On the other hand WPA3 is said to provide perfect forward secrecy. Is this because the key sharing process is done through the Dragonfly handshake which is based on the diffie hellman algorithm and thus retrieving the private keys (the random numbers generated as negotiated) is computationally intractable?

Comment: The exact way WPA3 achieves this isn't public yet. Or at least, I couldn't find anything other than an announcement that the standard was stabilized. Most likely, we'll have to wait some time before it is published. As for your second two questions, I answered them [on your previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/199596/165253).

Comment: This needs a more descriptive title